# Maven cli command to search packages

Tags: maven, command-line, command, command-line-interface, mvn-repo

Is there a command line command in Maven to search / find packages? Something similar to `npm search`:

```
# npm search indexeddb
NAME                      | DESCRIPTION          | AUTHOR          | DATE       | VERSION  | KEYWORDS                                                                             
indexeddb                 | A pure-JavaScript…   | =bigeasy        | 2014-02-13 | 0.0.0    | btree leveldb levelup binary mvcc database json b-tree concurrent persistence durable
lokijs                    | Fast document…       | =techfort       | 2021-04-20 | 1.5.12   | javascript document-oriented mmdb json nosql lokijs in-memory indexeddb
localforage               | Offline storage,…    | =tofumatt       | 2021-08-18 | 1.10.0   | indexeddb localstorage storage websql
idb-keyval                | A…                   | =jaffathecake   | 2022-01-11 | 6.1.0    | idb indexeddb store keyval localstorage storage promise
idb                       | A small wrapper…     | =jaffathecake   | 2022-03-14 | 7.0.1    | 
y-indexeddb               | IndexedDB database…  | =dmonad         | 2022-01-21 | 9.0.7    | Yjs CRDT offline shared editing collaboration concurrency
minimongo                 | Client-side mongo…   | =broncha…       | 2022-05-23 | 6.12.4   | mongodb mongo minimongo IndexedDb WebSQL storage
@karsegard/indexeddb-expo | Export/import an…    | =fdt2k          | 2021-09-20 | 2.1.4    | IndexedDB JSON import export serialize deserialize backup restore
rt-import                 |                      |                 |            |          |                                                                  
dexie                     | A Minimalistic…      | =anders.ekdahl… | 2022-04-27 | 3.2.2    | indexeddb browser database
fortune-indexeddb         | IndexedDB adapter…   | =daliwali       | 2021-06-17 | 1.2.1    | indexeddb adapter
bytewise                  | Binary…              | =deanlandolt    | 2015-06-19 | 1.1.0    | binary sort collation serialization leveldb indexeddb
fortune-localforage       | localForage adapter… | =acoreyj        | 2018-08-29 | 1.3.0    | indexeddb adapter
idb-kv                    | A tiny key value…    | =kayleepop      | 2019-09-28 | 2.1.1    | idb kv indexeddb key value api batch performance
idbkv-chunk-store         | Abstract chunk…      | =kayleepop      | 2019-05-16 | 1.1.2    | idb indexeddb chunk store abstract batch batching performance fast small writes
fortune-indexeddb-with-bu | IndexedDB adapter…   | =acoreyj        | 2018-05-29 | 1.0.3    | indexeddb adapter
ndle                      |                      |                 |            |          |                  
fake-indexeddb            | Fake IndexedDB: a…   | =dumbmatter     | 2022-06-08 | 3.1.8    | indexeddb datastore database embedded nosql in-memory polyfill shim
redux-persist-indexeddb-s | Redux Persist…       | =mpintos        | 2019-12-11 | 1.0.4    | redux redux-persist indexeddb
torage                    |                      |                 |            |          |                              
indexeddb-export-import   | Export/import an…    | =polarisation   | 2021-11-16 | 2.1.5    | IndexedDB JSON import export serialize deserialize backup restore
@n1md7/indexeddb-promise  | Indexed DB wrapper…  | =n1md7          | 2022-05-08 | 7.0.4    | db indexed-db promise indexed npm package
@sighmir/indexeddb-export | Export/import an…    | =sighmir        | 2019-12-30 | 1.1.1    | IndexedDB JSON import export serialize deserialize
-import
```

If yes, how can I find packages for a search string?

Comment: Never heard of such a thing, you usually search on https://search.maven.org

Comment: Yes there is a command line tool 

```brew install mcs```

https://github.com/mthmulders/mcs